# WordPress Site Breaks When a Visitor Searches for "insert"

Tags: php, wordpress, search, insert

A client that sells industrial plumbing parts just told me that their site breaks every time a visitor searches for an *insert* through their page.  Basically rather than return the page of search results, we end up seeing the *Welcome to Apache* page that displays until you put a website in place.

Every other search term seems to work.

Comment: I think you should check your log files. We can't help without having such a thing posted, but please sanitize any sensitive information like IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

(For a full description of the problem and the detailed troubleshooting steps, find the details at: http://www.reich-consulting.net/2015/06/09/ithemes-security-plugin-and-dangerous-search-queries/)

**Solution:**

The problem was caused by the iThemes Security plug-in, which tries to be helpful by adding .htaccess rules that block potentially dangerous data from being sent to WordPress.  I popped open the *.htaccess* file and discovered the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
```

That rule causes any requests with "insert" in the query string to be dropped before it's ever passed to WordPress. Removing it allowed the site to function as expected.